# send UISlider values using Multipeer Connectivity wifi/bluetooth

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, wifi, multipeer-connectivity

Im starting to create music production applications and the Multipeer Connectivity can come in handy!!!

I can set up a connection between two iDevices. But my goal is to send UISlider values from one device to another where they will go straight into my sound engine on the host device).

Should I use an NSStream or just send NSData (perhaps using MCSessionSendDataUnreliable)?
And if NSData then when? should I attach a selector for UIControlEventValueChanged???

I'm having trouble with everything at the moment on this one task...

The multipeer connectivity framework seems awesome, and I think many people could use this

Comment: Do you have a link to your project? I can have a look since I have a few devices here, and I can incorporate the code I have in my other connectivity project to see if I can qickly set something up for you for UISlider values etc?

Comment: YES plz... I made a quick project that should work on any device:https://github.com/DanMoore24/WirelesSlider

Comment: Whats the difference between this project and your current project? Im confused.

Comment: No difference. I took out all the CoreAudio and a bunch of VCs

Answer (score 0):

All of your ideas are spot on. The choice between `NSStream` and `NSData` will come down to how *frequently the sliders are updated*. Since you'll be doing music production, time synchronization will be crucial (especially if you are doing any tasks with MIDI).

If time and latency is indeed a factor, I would recommend going the `NSStream` route, and then routing all packets through that stream. You can easily implement this idea using `NSData` and then determine if the latency is an issue.

Roughly what you will need to do, is package up the data you want to transmit as an `NSData` and send it over the wire. You have a two options here: You can either create C structs and initialize data from pointers to those structs. Or you can create an `NSObject` subclass that conforms to the `NSSecureCoding` protocol. Then use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to convert the class to an `NSData`.